# Use verification link instead of verification code AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-amplify

I need to verify the user with email verification by clicking a verification link like the firebase default template instead of entering a verification code on signup.

Here's my code

```
export const signUp = async (username, password, details) => {
  try {
    const {user} = await Auth.signUp({
      username,
      password,
      attributes: {
        ...details,
      },
    });
    console.log(user);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error signing up:', error);
  }
};
```

I am not able to find this setting in the admin panel also.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go into your cognito pool settings.

Under Message Customization -> Verification type

Select Link instead of code.

Answer (score 2):

In the new console experience, it is under:

User Pools > {{YOUR_USER_POOL}} > Messaging > Message Template > Verification message

[image: Verification Type for Email]